# pageControl.opaque = false in swift not work

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I use this code to remove any color from page view controller indicator but the standard while color always appear. I use this code:

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
pageControl.opaque = false
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

I appreciate any idea. Thanks

Comment: Please check the documentation for `opaque` it does not ever affect what the view looks like. You need to use something else.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of: `pageControl.opaque = false` use:

```
pageControl.alpha = 0.0
```

or

```
pageControl.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly not work. In fact the dots disappears.

Comment: Plese post a screenshot of the desired and the actual result.

Comment: Many things for your collaboration but I don't have enough time and I delivery the APP tomorrow morning. So, I've resolved the problem in another way, not the best !